# After OS upgrade, ZFS disk in pool is unavailable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs

**UPDATE 2019-06-16**
I've tried  `sudo zpool replace tank /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840GFH2` and get

```
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840GFH2-part1 is part of active pool 'tank'
```

Should I use -f, or am I likely to break something?

---

**FULL POST**

Okay, I have 3 ZFS pools on my home file server. None of them are root.

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 today and did a zpool status check and got this result:

```
     pool: mediatank
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
        still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
        the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
        the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
  scan: resilvered 1.62T in 14h25m with 0 errors on Mon Mar 14 01:51:38 2016
config:

        NAME                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        mediatank                             ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                            ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_14TRRNVGS  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_X4IPL2SGS  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: slowtank
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
        corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
        entire pool from backup.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: resilvered 436M in 0h0m with 0 errors on Tue Dec 29 20:45:13 2015
config:

        NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        slowtank                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK11B1B9HXPYSF  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK1101B9HXP2ZT  ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-1                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK2171B9HYRASL  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST2000DM001-1CH164_Z240TLE8             ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: 2 data errors, use '-v' for a list

  pool: tank
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
        invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
        functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: resilvered 116M in 0h0m with 0 errors on Fri Jun 14 02:00:54 2019
config:

        NAME                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank                                  DEGRADED     0     0     0
          mirror-0                            DEGRADED     0     0     0
            ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840GECZ  ONLINE       0     0     0
            18019629936018899145              UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/sdm1

errors: No known data errors
```

Ignore the data errors on 'slowtank'. That was from an incident last year where the disks lost power briefly. The damaged files were restored and I never figured out how to clear the error.

Here's the problem:

The disk listed as 'unavailable' in the 'tank' pool seems to be healthy. The pool is indicating that it was sdm1, but sdm is the name for my system disk, so ??? how that happened. It's actually sdk according to `blkid`.

I am not sure how this happened, as I made no hardware changes to the machine.

During the first stage of the upgrade, zfs was removed and I had to reinstall it. This is possibly where the problem originated.

I thought I might export and import the pool, but when I tried to export 'tank', I got:

```
umount: /tank/hrududu: target is busy.
cannot unmount '/tank/hrududu': umount failed
```

Any help much appreciated.

(And yes, I should scrub my pools more often. I used to have it scheduled, but I disabled it a few years ago when I had a bout of insomnia and the noise of the disks thudding away all night was annoying the crap out of me. I'm better and I'll start scrubbing them again, I promise.)

Commenter requests:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK1101B9HXP2ZT -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK1101B9HXP2ZT-part1 -> ../../sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK1101B9HXP2ZT-part9 -> ../../sdf9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK11B1B9HXPYSF -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK11B1B9HXPYSF-part1 -> ../../sde1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK11B1B9HXPYSF-part9 -> ../../sde9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK2171B9HYRASL -> ../../sdh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK2171B9HYRASL-part1 -> ../../sdh1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK2171B9HYRASL-part9 -> ../../sdh9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 ata-HITACHI_HTS542525K9SA00_080724BB6F02WDJWHR1G -> ../../sdm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-HITACHI_HTS542525K9SA00_080724BB6F02WDJWHR1G-part1 -> ../../sdm1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-HITACHI_HTS542525K9SA00_080724BB6F02WDJWHR1G-part2 -> ../../sdm2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-HITACHI_HTS542525K9SA00_080724BB6F02WDJWHR1G-part5 -> ../../sdm5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 ata-ST2000DM001-1CH164_Z240TLE8 -> ../../sdg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-ST2000DM001-1CH164_Z240TLE8-part1 -> ../../sdg1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-ST2000DM001-1CH164_Z240TLE8-part9 -> ../../sdg9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840GECZ -> ../../sdl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840GECZ-part1 -> ../../sdl1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840GECZ-part9 -> ../../sdl9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840GFH2 -> ../../sdk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840GFH2-part1 -> ../../sdk1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840GFH2-part9 -> ../../sdk9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_14TRRNVGS -> ../../sdj
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_14TRRNVGS-part1 -> ../../sdj1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_14TRRNVGS-part9 -> ../../sdj9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_X4IPL2SGS -> ../../sdi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_X4IPL2SGS-part1 -> ../../sdi1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_X4IPL2SGS-part9 -> ../../sdi9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 20:48 usb-Generic-_Compact_Flash_20060413092100000-0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 20:48 usb-Generic-_MS_MS-Pro_20060413092100000-0:3 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 20:48 usb-Generic-_SD_MMC_20060413092100000-0:2 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 20:48 usb-Generic-_SM_xD-Picture_20060413092100000-0:1 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000039ff4d86cc7 -> ../../sdj
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000039ff4d86cc7-part1 -> ../../sdj1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000039ff4d86cc7-part9 -> ../../sdj9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000039ff4e5feb4 -> ../../sdi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000039ff4e5feb4-part1 -> ../../sdi1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000039ff4e5feb4-part9 -> ../../sdi9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000c50050b9ca36 -> ../../sdg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000c50050b9ca36-part1 -> ../../sdg1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000c50050b9ca36-part9 -> ../../sdg9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000c50090dfe188 -> ../../sdk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000c50090dfe188-part1 -> ../../sdk1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000c50090dfe188-part9 -> ../../sdk9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000c50090e04df8 -> ../../sdl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000c50090e04df8-part1 -> ../../sdl1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000c50090e04df8-part9 -> ../../sdl9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca222db2116 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca222db2116-part1 -> ../../sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca222db2116-part9 -> ../../sdf9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca222db2454 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca222db2454-part1 -> ../../sde1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca222db2454-part9 -> ../../sde9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca222db9a27 -> ../../sdh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca222db9a27-part1 -> ../../sdh1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca222db9a27-part9 -> ../../sdh9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca533e8b001 -> ../../sdm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca533e8b001-part1 -> ../../sdm1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca533e8b001-part2 -> ../../sdm2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 15 21:30 wwn-0x5000cca533e8b001-part5 -> ../../sdm5
```

Output of `sudo zpool status -P`

```
 pool: mediatank
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
        still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
        the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
        the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
  scan: resilvered 1.62T in 14h25m with 0 errors on Mon Mar 14 01:51:38 2016
config:

        NAME                                                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        mediatank                                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/disk/by-id/ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_14TRRNVGS-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/disk/by-id/ata-TOSHIBA_DT01ACA300_X4IPL2SGS-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: slowtank
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
        corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
        entire pool from backup.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: resilvered 436M in 0h0m with 0 errors on Tue Dec 29 20:45:13 2015
config:

        NAME                                                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        slowtank                                                              ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK11B1B9HXPYSF-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK1101B9HXP2ZT-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-1                                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK2171B9HYRASL-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST2000DM001-1CH164_Z240TLE8-part1             ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: 2 data errors, use '-v' for a list

  pool: tank
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
        invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
        functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: resilvered 116M in 0h0m with 0 errors on Fri Jun 14 02:00:54 2019
config:

        NAME                                                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank                                                        DEGRADED     0     0     0
          mirror-0                                                  DEGRADED     0     0     0
            /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000AS0002-1NA17Z_Z840GECZ-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
            18019629936018899145                                    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/sdm1

errors: No known data errors
```

Comment: Pools are in fact not configured by disk name or anything but by pool ID. Did you perhaps clone an entire pool bit-by-bit at some point in the past? // Also, by looking at the disk sizes, everything appears to be correct. There are no *swapped* disks. You are simple one disk *short*. // Also, it appears you never scrub your pools. You really should do that.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Point by point:
- It's my understanding that disks can be identified to ZFS by their system IDs (sda, sdb, etc.) or by their unique names, and/or some other ways I can't remember. I was trying to make clear that this error didn't happen because I plugged in a USB drive and the disk assignments changed. (Although sdc and sdm switched during the upgrade, it seems.
- No, I have not cloned a pool bit-by-bit. Pools were created and data was moved onto them manually within the OS.
- You are right regarding the swapped disks. I just realized that the other Seagate is a 2GB.

Comment: What confused me is that the unavailable disk is the same model as its pool-mate, but is identified differently.

I'll edit the main post to deal with your observations.

Comment: And I will start scrubbing the disks again. I promise.

Comment: The `18019629936018899145` is the GUID of what was presumably a 2+ TB disk. `slowtank.mirror-1` appears to be in order (both members are 2TB). A disk should not just move from one pool to another like you're implying - that would be a major flaw, and I'd suspect it didn't happen. Can you replace the status output with `zpool status -P`, and share the output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/`? I'd conclude that there is a disk missing from your system... do you have notes about the pool structures (disks / GUIDs / etc...) from before the upgrade?

Comment: Hi Attie. You are correct that the disks didn't switch. You must be reading an older cached version of my question. I edited it about 25 minutes ago. It seems that the system ID for the disk might have changed during my upgrade? Anyway, the problem is limited to the 'tank' pool and a disc with a missing label.